# SQLite Adding a prefix to value after ordering

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite, a column of numbers have been orderd in descending order by:

```
ORDER BY Subtotal DESC
```

Is there a way to add a prefix after the numbers have been ordered in descending order? For example a '$' Prefix in front of the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can just select a column that has more formatting, e.g. `('$' ||  Subtotal) AS FormattedSubtotal` while continuing to sort by `Subtotal`.

Comment: @forpas Oop. Changed to use the concat operator. Thanks.